# Incrementally copying files over a network

Tags: networking

We use laptops in our company. We connect to the network from our respective workstations. We usually copy files from other systems which are connected to the network. The problem is that the person may disconnect (go to meetings, leave office etc) from the network at his wish, because of which the copying process gets terminated.

How can I handle this scenario? Is there a scenario where I can start the copying process from the point of termination?

PS: We use Windows XP

Comment: get windows live mesh @ www.mesh.com

Answer (score 1):

[Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) with the /Z switch will restart partial copies from the last successful block that has been copied. I can't remember if it is built in to XP or not (I think not) but the Windows 2003 Resource Kit version works fine on Windows XP.

The /Z switch makes Robocopy somewhat less efficient but if you're copying large files it can help.

Answer (score 0):

actually, there is an update to robocopy - they now call it RichCopy - 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx

hope that helps, the new richcopy is pretty robust in what it can do.

Comment: It's not an update or replacement to robocopy, it's an unsupported utility written by a Microsoft employee which can be used as an alternative to robocopy.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Microsoft's Background Intelligent Transfer Service, [BITS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362708.aspx).  This is basically a download/upload manager (included in Windows XP) that you can control with the command-line utility [BITSadmin.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362812.aspx).

I have not tried this, but you *should* be able to put together a Logon/Logoff/Startup/Shutdown script that utilizes BITS to do what you want.  BITS also has the advantage of being able to configure how much bandwidth to use, etc.  You could probably even get fancy and detect the connection and adjust bandwidth accordingly, e.g. BITS could continue to retrieve data over a VPN from a user's home without saturating the connection.

Here's another [Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.08.utilityspotlight.aspx) with some code samples for using BITS.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.dropbox.com/

this will sync over the LAN first the net second

2+ gigs free